# Tortoise Helper Program

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Recently, the following code was written to help automate some processes that are typically executed while working with a Mercurial database. What is shown below is basically a first draft of the program and was quickly written to test out the idea of creating a GUI tool for others to use.

**Question:** Are there any obvious flaws in how the program works or how the code is formatted and arranged that might be improved for future versions?

```
import sys
import subprocess
import tkFileDialog
import Tkinter

class TortoiseHelper(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.initialize()
        self.create_controls()
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            if TortoiseHelper.validate_repo(sys.argv[1]):
                self.repoPath.set(sys.argv[1])
                self.refresh_repo()


    def change_repo(self):
        newPath = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=self)
        if TortoiseHelper.validate_repo(newPath):
            self.repoPath.set(newPath)
            self.refresh_repo()


    def create_controls(self):
        mainFrame = Tkinter.Frame(self)
        mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=(Tkinter.N, Tkinter.E, Tkinter.S, Tkinter.W))
        mainFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        mainFrame.rowconfigure(13, weight=1)

        repoLabel = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        repoLabel['text'] = 'Repository'
        repoLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

        lblRepo = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        lblRepo['textvariable'] = self.repoPath
        lblRepo['relief'] = Tkinter.SUNKEN
        lblRepo['anchor'] = Tkinter.W
        lblRepo.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=4, pady=2, sticky=(Tkinter.E, Tkinter.W))

        btnRefresh = Tkinter.Button(mainFrame)
        btnRefresh['text'] = 'Refresh'
        btnRefresh['command'] = self.refresh_repo
        btnRefresh.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2)

        btnChange = Tkinter.Button(mainFrame)
        btnChange['text'] = 'Change'
        btnChange['command'] = self.change_repo
        btnChange.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=2)

        statusLabel = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        statusLabel['text'] = 'Status'
        statusLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(Tkinter.N, Tkinter.E))

        lblStatus = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        lblStatus['textvariable'] = self.repoStatus
        lblStatus['relief'] = Tkinter.SUNKEN
        lblStatus['anchor'] = Tkinter.W
        lblStatus['justify'] = Tkinter.LEFT
        lblStatus.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=4, pady=2, sticky=(Tkinter.E, Tkinter.W))

        branchLabel = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        branchLabel['text'] = 'Branch'
        branchLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

        lblBranch = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        lblBranch['textvariable'] = self.repoBranch
        lblBranch['relief'] = Tkinter.SUNKEN
        lblBranch['anchor'] = Tkinter.W
        lblBranch.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=4, pady=2, sticky=(Tkinter.E, Tkinter.W))

        chkCommit = Tkinter.Checkbutton(mainFrame)
        chkCommit['text'] = 'Commit'
        chkCommit['variable'] = self.optionCommit
        chkCommit['command'] = self.on_commit_click
        chkCommit.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        branchNameLabel = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        branchNameLabel['text'] = 'New branch name'
        branchNameLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

        self.entBranchName = Tkinter.Entry(mainFrame)
        self.entBranchName['textvariable'] = self.newBranchName
        self.entBranchName.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=(Tkinter.E, Tkinter.W))

        commitMessageLabel = Tkinter.Label(mainFrame)
        commitMessageLabel['text'] = 'Commit message'
        commitMessageLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

        self.txtCommitMessage = Tkinter.Text(mainFrame)
        self.txtCommitMessage['height'] = 4
        self.txtCommitMessage.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=2, sticky=(Tkinter.E, Tkinter.W))

        self.chkClose = Tkinter.Checkbutton(mainFrame)
        self.chkClose['text'] = 'Close branch'
        self.chkClose['variable'] = self.optionClose
        self.chkClose.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        self.chkMergeTest = Tkinter.Checkbutton(mainFrame)
        self.chkMergeTest['text'] = 'Merge with Test'
        self.chkMergeTest['variable'] = self.optionMergeTest
        self.chkMergeTest['command'] = self.on_merge_test_click
        self.chkMergeTest.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        self.chkMergeTestSilent = Tkinter.Checkbutton(mainFrame)
        self.chkMergeTestSilent['text'] = 'Attempt silent merge'
        self.chkMergeTestSilent['variable'] = self.optionSilentMergeTest
        self.chkMergeTestSilent.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=20, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        self.chkMergeProduction = Tkinter.Checkbutton(mainFrame)
        self.chkMergeProduction['text'] = 'Merge with Production'
        self.chkMergeProduction['variable'] = self.optionMergeProduction
        self.chkMergeProduction['command'] = self.on_merge_production_click
        self.chkMergeProduction.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        self.chkMergeProductionSilent = Tkinter.Checkbutton(mainFrame)
        self.chkMergeProductionSilent['text'] = 'Attempt silent merge'
        self.chkMergeProductionSilent['variable'] = self.optionSilentMergeProduction
        self.chkMergeProductionSilent.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=20, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        chkPush = Tkinter.Checkbutton(mainFrame)
        chkPush['text'] = 'Push'
        chkPush['variable'] = self.optionPush
        chkPush.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        btnRun = Tkinter.Button(mainFrame)
        btnRun['text'] = 'Run'
        btnRun['command'] = self.run
        btnRun.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.W)

        btnCancel = Tkinter.Button(mainFrame)
        btnCancel['text'] = 'Cancel'
        btnCancel['command'] = self.quit
        btnCancel.grid(row=12, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=Tkinter.E)

        self.txtOutput = Tkinter.Text(mainFrame)
        self.txtOutput['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED
        self.txtOutput.grid(row=13, column=0, pady=4, columnspan=4, sticky=(Tkinter.N, Tkinter.E, Tkinter.S, Tkinter.W))
        self.txtOutput.tag_config('RED', foreground='red')
        self.txtOutput.tag_config('GRAY', foreground='gray')
        self.txtOutput.tag_config('BG_GRAY', background='gray')


    def initialize(self):
        # Initialize variables
        self.repoPath = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.repoStatus = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.repoBranch = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.optionCommit = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.newBranchName = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.optionClose = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.optionMergeTest = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.optionSilentMergeTest = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.optionMergeProduction = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.optionSilentMergeProduction = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.optionPush = Tkinter.IntVar()

        # Configure the window
        self.title('Tortoise Helper')
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.minsize(width=400, height=500)


    @staticmethod
    def is_special_branch(branchName):
        return branchName in ('Test', 'Production', 'Site Redesign')


    def on_commit_click(self):
        self.set_commit_fields_enabled()
        self.set_close_branch_option_enabled()
        self.set_merge_test_option_enabled()
        self.set_merge_production_option_enabled()


    def on_merge_production_click(self):
        self.set_silent_merge_production_option_enabled()


    def on_merge_test_click(self):
        self.set_silent_merge_test_option_enabled()


    def refresh_repo(self):
        path = self.repoPath.get()
        command = 'hg status -R ' + path
        uncommittedChanges = TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'] != ''
        repositoryStatus = ''
        if uncommittedChanges == 0:
            repositoryStatus = 'No uncommitted changes'
        elif uncommittedChanges == 1:
            repositoryStatus = '1 uncommitted change'
        else:
            repositoryStatus = str(uncommittedChanges) + ' uncommitted changes'
        command = 'hg incoming -q -R ' + path
        incomingChanges = len(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['output'])
        if incomingChanges == 0:
            repositoryStatus += '\nNo incoming changes'
        elif incomingChanges == 1:
            repositoryStatus += '\n1 incoming change'
        else:
            repositoryStatus += '\n' + str(incomingChanges) + ' incoming changes'
        command = 'hg outgoing -q -R ' + path
        outgoingChanges = len(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['output'])
        if outgoingChanges == 0:
            repositoryStatus += '\nNo outgoing changes'
        elif outgoingChanges == 1:
            repositoryStatus += '\n1 outgoing change'
        else:
            repositoryStatus += '\n' + str(outgoingChanges) + ' outgoing changes'
        self.repoStatus.set(repositoryStatus)
        command = 'hg branch -R ' + path
        branchName = TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output']
        self.repoBranch.set(branchName)
        self.optionCommit.set(0)
        self.set_commit_fields_enabled()
        self.set_close_branch_option_enabled()
        self.set_merge_production_option_enabled()
        self.set_merge_test_option_enabled()
        self.optionPush.set(0)
        self.txtOutput.delete(1.0, Tkinter.END)


    def run(self):
        # Determine what needs to be done
        command = ''
        currentRevision = ''
        useMergeDialog = False
        path = self.repoPath.get()
        command = 'hg branch -R ' + path
        currentBranchName = TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output']
        commit = self.optionCommit.get() == 1
        newBranchName = self.newBranchName.get()
        changeBranch = newBranchName != currentBranchName
        commitMessage = self.txtCommitMessage.get(1.0, Tkinter.END).strip()
        closeBranch = self.optionClose.get() == 1
        mergeWithTest = self.optionMergeTest.get() == 1
        silentMergeTest = self.optionSilentMergeTest.get() == 1
        mergeWithProduction = self.optionMergeProduction.get() == 1
        silentMergeProduction = self.optionSilentMergeProduction.get() == 1
        push = self.optionPush.get() == 1

        # Validate
        if commit:
            if newBranchName == '':
                self.write_output('Branch name is required.', 'RED')
                return
            if TortoiseHelper.is_special_branch(newBranchName):
                self.write_output('Branch name is not valid.', 'RED')
                return
            if commitMessage == '':
                self.write_output('Commit message is required', 'RED')
                return
        if closeBranch:
            if not commit:
                if TortoiseHelper.is_special_branch(currentBranchName):
                    self.write_output('Cannot close branch ' + currentBranchName + '.', 'RED')
                    return

        # Execute
        if commit:
            if changeBranch:
                self.write_output('Changing branch name', 'BG_GRAY')
                command = 'hg branch -R ' + path + ' "' + newBranchName + '"'
                self.write_output(command)
                self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')
                currentBranchName = newBranchName

            self.write_output('Committing', 'BG_GRAY')
            command = 'hg commit -R ' + path + ' -v "--message=' + commitMessage + '"'
            self.write_output(command)
            self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')

        if closeBranch:
            self.write_output('Closing', 'BG_GRAY')
            command = 'hg commit -R ' + path + ' -v --close-branch "--message=Close ' + currentBranchName + ' branch"'
            self.write_output(command)
            self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')

        if mergeWithTest or mergeWithProduction:
            command = 'hg identify -i -R ' + path
            self.write_output(command)
            currentRevision = TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output']

        if mergeWithTest:
            self.write_output('Pulling', 'BG_GRAY')
            command = 'hg pull -R ' + path
            self.write_output(command)
            self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')
            self.write_output('Updating to Test', 'BG_GRAY')
            command = 'hg update -R ' + path + ' Test'
            self.write_output(command)
            self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')
            if silentMergeTest:
                useMergeDialog = False
                self.write_output('Attempting silent merge', 'BG_GRAY')
                command = 'hg merge -R ' + path + ' -t internal:merge -r ' + currentRevision
                self.write_output(command)
                command_result = TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)
                self.write_output(command_result['full_output'], 'GRAY')
                if command_result['return_code'] == 1:
                    self.write_output('Silent merge failed; returning to Test branch', 'BG_GRAY')
                    command = 'hg update -C -R ' + path
                    self.write_output(command)
                    self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')
                    useMergeDialog = True
            else:
                useMergeDialog = True
            if useMergeDialog:
                self.write_output('Launching merge dialog', 'BG_GRAY')
                command = 'thg merge -R ' + path + ' -r ' + currentRevision
                self.write_output(command)
                self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')

        if mergeWithProduction:
            self.write_output('Pulling', 'BG_GRAY')
            command = 'hg pull -R ' + path
            self.write_output(command)
            self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')
            self.write_output('Updating to Production', 'BG_GRAY')
            command = 'hg update -R ' + path + ' Production'
            self.write_output(command)
            self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')
            if silentMergeProduction:
                useMergeDialog = False
                self.write_output('Attempting silent merge', 'BG_GRAY')
                command = 'hg merge -R ' + path + ' -t internal:merge -r ' + currentRevision
                self.write_output(command)
                command_result = TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)
                self.write_output(command_result['full_output'], 'GRAY')
                if command_result['return_code'] == 1:
                    self.write_output('Silent merge failed; returning to Production branch', 'BG_GRAY')
                    command = 'hg update -C -R ' + path
                    self.write_output(command)
                    self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')
                    useMergeDialog = True
            else:
                useMergeDialog = True
            if useMergeDialog:
                self.write_output('Launching merge dialog', 'BG_GRAY')
                command = 'thg merge -R ' + path + ' -r ' + currentRevision
                self.write_output(command)
                self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')

        if push:
            self.write_output('Pushing', 'BG_GRAY')
            command = 'hg push -R ' + path + ' --new-branch'
            self.write_output(command)
            self.write_output(TortoiseHelper.run_command(command)['full_output'], 'GRAY')


    @staticmethod
    def run_command(command):
        output = []
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in process.stdout:
            output.append(line.strip())
        return { "return_code": process.wait(), "output": output, "full_output": '\n'.join(output) }


    def set_close_branch_option_enabled(self):
        if TortoiseHelper.is_special_branch(self.repoBranch.get()) and self.optionCommit.get() == 0:
            self.chkClose['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED
            self.optionClose.set(0)
        else:
            self.chkClose['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL


    def set_commit_fields_enabled(self):
        if self.optionCommit.get() == 1:
            self.entBranchName['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL
            self.txtCommitMessage['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL
        else:
            self.entBranchName['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED
            self.newBranchName.set(self.repoBranch.get())
            self.txtCommitMessage['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED
            self.txtCommitMessage.delete(1.0, Tkinter.END)


    def set_merge_production_option_enabled(self):
        if TortoiseHelper.is_special_branch(self.repoBranch.get()) and self.optionCommit.get() == 0:
            self.chkMergeProduction['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED
            self.optionMergeProduction.set(0)
        else:
            self.chkMergeProduction['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL
        self.set_silent_merge_production_option_enabled()


    def set_merge_test_option_enabled(self):
        if TortoiseHelper.is_special_branch(self.repoBranch.get()) and self.optionCommit.get() == 0:
            self.chkMergeTest['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED
            self.optionMergeTest.set(0)
        else:
            self.chkMergeTest['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL
        self.set_silent_merge_test_option_enabled()


    def set_silent_merge_production_option_enabled(self):
        if self.optionMergeProduction.get() == 1:
            self.chkMergeProductionSilent['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL
        else:
            self.optionSilentMergeProduction.set(0)
            self.chkMergeProductionSilent['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED


    def set_silent_merge_test_option_enabled(self):
        if self.optionMergeTest.get() == 1:
            self.chkMergeTestSilent['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL
        else:
            self.optionSilentMergeTest.set(0)
            self.chkMergeTestSilent['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED


    @staticmethod
    def validate_repo(path):
        return TortoiseHelper.run_command('hg id -R ' + path)['return_code'] == 0


    def write_output(self, value, tag=''):
        self.txtOutput['state'] = Tkinter.NORMAL
        if len(self.txtOutput.get(1.0, Tkinter.END)) > 1:
            self.txtOutput.insert(Tkinter.END, '\n')
        self.txtOutput.insert(Tkinter.END, value, tag)
        self.txtOutput['state'] = Tkinter.DISABLED


def main():
    helper = TortoiseHelper()
    helper.mainloop()


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

Comment: While I'm not a pro with Mercurial or Tortise or TKinter, you have a lot of style violations here that prompts me having to [link you to the PEP8 style rules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), specifically line breaks and variable naming.  Also, why are you trying to construct the window *outside* of the `__init__`, where you very likely should be constructing everything for the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code could be redesigned to make porting to Python 3.X easier in the future. A lot of refactoring is needed, and the following is only a partial redesign. The biggest problem that the program still has is how it locks up while trying to complete long-running operations. My recommendation is to take the following code and use at the starting point for an even more detailed rewrite.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
# http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144238
from __future__ import division             # PEP 238
from __future__ import absolute_import      # PEP 328
from __future__ import print_function       # PEP 3105
from __future__ import unicode_literals     # PEP 3112

import subprocess
import sys

import Tkinter as tkinter
from Tkconstants import *

import tkFileDialog
tkinter.filedialog = tkFileDialog
del tkFileDialog


class TortoiseTool(tkinter.Frame, object):

    __DEFAULT = object()

    @classmethod
    def main(cls, argv=None):
        tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        # Configure the main window.
        root.title('Tortoise Helper')
        root.wm_minsize(400, 500)
        # Create the application with placement.
        tool = cls(root, argv=argv)
        tool.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        # Configure the resizing capabilities.
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf=__DEFAULT, **kw):
        argv = kw.pop('argv', None)
        super(TortoiseTool, self).__init__(master, self.__eval(cnf, {}), **kw)
        # Initialize the variables used with the widgets.
        self.repo_path = tkinter.StringVar(self)
        self.repo_status = tkinter.StringVar(self)
        self.repo_branch = tkinter.StringVar(self)
        self.option_commit = tkinter.BooleanVar(self)
        self.new_branch_name = tkinter.StringVar(self)
        self.option_close = tkinter.BooleanVar(self)
        self.option_merge_test = tkinter.BooleanVar(self)
        self.option_silent_merge_test = tkinter.BooleanVar(self)
        self.option_merge_production = tkinter.BooleanVar(self)
        self.option_silent_merge_production = tkinter.BooleanVar(self)
        self.option_push = tkinter.BooleanVar(self)
        # Create all widgets used in the applications.
        self.repo_label = tkinter.Label(self, text='Repository')
        self.lbl_repo = tkinter.Label(
            self, textvariable=self.repo_path, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W
        )
        self.btn_refresh = tkinter.Button(
            self, text='Refresh', command=self.refresh_repo
        )
        self.btn_change = tkinter.Button(
            self, text='Change', command=self.change_repo
        )
        self.status_label = tkinter.Label(self, text='Status')
        self.lbl_status = tkinter.Label(
            self, textvariable=self.repo_status, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W,
            justify=LEFT
        )
        self.branch_label = tkinter.Label(self, text='Branch')
        self.lbl_branch = tkinter.Label(
            self, textvariable=self.repo_branch, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W
        )
        self.chk_commit = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Commit', variable=self.option_commit,
            command=self.on_commit_click
        )
        self.ent_branch_name = tkinter.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.new_branch_name
        )
        self.branch_name_label = tkinter.Label(self, text='New branch name')
        self.commit_message_label = tkinter.Label(self, text='Commit message')
        self.txt_commit_message = tkinter.Text(self, height=4)
        self.chk_close = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Close branch', variable=self.option_close
        )
        self.chk_merge_test = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Merge with Test', variable=self.option_merge_test,
            command=self.on_merge_test_click
        )
        self.chk_merge_test_silent = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Attempt silent merge', state=DISABLED,
            variable=self.option_silent_merge_test
        )
        self.chk_merge_production = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Merge with Production',
            variable=self.option_merge_production,
            command=self.on_merge_production_click
        )
        self.chk_merge_production_silent = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Attempt silent merge', state=DISABLED,
            variable=self.option_silent_merge_production
        )
        self.chk_push = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Push', variable=self.option_push
        )
        self.btn_run = tkinter.Button(self, text='Run', command=self.run)
        self.btn_cancel = tkinter.Button(
            self, text='Cancel', command=self.quit
        )
        self.txt_output = tkinter.Text(self, state=DISABLED)
        # Finish the setup process and configure parameters.
        self.grid_all_widgets()
        self.adjust_resizing_weights()
        self.configure_widget_options()
        self.process_command_line_arguments(argv)

    def grid_all_widgets(self):
        self.repo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.lbl_repo.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky=EW)
        self.btn_refresh.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2)
        self.btn_change.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=2)
        self.status_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NE)
        self.lbl_status.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky=EW)
        self.branch_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.lbl_branch.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky=EW)
        self.chk_commit.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
        self.branch_name_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.ent_branch_name.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=EW)
        self.commit_message_label.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.txt_commit_message.grid(
            row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=2, sticky=EW
        )
        self.chk_close.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
        self.chk_merge_test.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
        self.chk_merge_test_silent.grid(
            row=8, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=20, sticky=W
        )
        self.chk_merge_production.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
        self.chk_merge_production_silent.grid(
            row=10, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=20, sticky=W
        )
        self.chk_push.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
        self.btn_run.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.btn_cancel.grid(row=12, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=E)
        self.txt_output.grid(
            row=13, column=0, pady=4, columnspan=4, sticky=NSEW
        )

    def adjust_resizing_weights(self):
        self.grid_rowconfigure(13, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def configure_widget_options(self):
        self.txt_output.tag_configure('RED', foreground='red')
        self.txt_output.tag_configure('GRAY', foreground='gray')
        self.txt_output.tag_configure('BG_GRAY', background='gray')

    def process_command_line_arguments(self, argv):
        if argv is not None and len(argv) > 1:
            self.validate_and_refresh(argv[1])

    def validate_and_refresh(self, repo):
        if self.validate_repo(repo):
            self.repo_path.set(repo)
            self.refresh_repo()

    @classmethod
    def __eval(cls, obj, default):
        return default if obj is cls.__DEFAULT else obj

    @staticmethod
    def validate_repo(path):
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(('hg', 'id', '-R', path))
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def refresh_repo(self):
        path = self.repo_path.get()
        repository_status = '\n'.join(
            self.format_count(
                len(get_output(command).splitlines()), message
            ) for command, message in (
                (('hg', 'status', '-R', path), 'uncommitted change'),
                (('hg', 'incoming', '-q', '-R', path), 'incoming change'),
                (('hg', 'outgoing', '-q', '-R', path), 'outgoing change')
            )
        )
        self.repo_status.set(repository_status)
        command = 'hg', 'branch', '-R', path
        self.repo_branch.set(subprocess.check_output(command).strip())
        self.reset_options()
        self.txt_output.delete(1.0, END)

    @staticmethod
    def format_count(count, message):
        return ('No {message}s', '1 {message}', '{count} {message}s')[
            min(count, 2)
        ].format(**locals())

    def reset_options(self, reset_commit=True):
        if reset_commit:
            self.option_commit.set(False)
        self.option_close.set(False)
        self.option_merge_test.set(False)
        self.on_merge_test_click()
        self.option_merge_production.set(False)
        self.on_merge_production_click()
        self.option_push.set(False)

    def change_repo(self):
        self.validate_and_refresh(tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(parent=self))

    def on_commit_click(self):
        self.reset_options(False)

    def on_merge_test_click(self):
        if self.option_merge_test.get():
            self.chk_merge_test_silent['state'] = NORMAL
        else:
            self.chk_merge_test_silent['state'] = DISABLED
            self.option_silent_merge_test.set(False)

    def on_merge_production_click(self):
        if self.option_merge_production.get():
            self.chk_merge_production_silent['state'] = NORMAL
        else:
            self.chk_merge_production_silent['state'] = DISABLED
            self.option_silent_merge_production.set(False)

    def run(self):
        path = self.repo_path.get()
        current_branch_name = subprocess.check_output(
            ('hg', 'branch', '-R', path)
        ).strip()
        if self.run_is_valid(current_branch_name):
            current_branch_name = self.run_commit(path, current_branch_name)
            self.run_close(path, current_branch_name)
            current_revision = self.get_current_revision(path)
            self.run_merge_test(path, current_revision)
            self.run_merge_production(path, current_revision)
            self.run_push(path)

    def run_is_valid(self, current_branch_name):
        option_commit = self.option_commit.get()
        if option_commit:
            new_branch_name = self.new_branch_name.get()
            if not new_branch_name:
                self.write_output('Branch name is required.', 'RED')
                return False
            if self.is_special_branch(new_branch_name):
                self.write_output('Branch name is not valid.', 'RED')
                return False
            if not self.txt_commit_message.get(1.0, END).strip():
                self.write_output('Commit message is required.', 'RED')
                return False
        if self.option_close.get() and not option_commit and \
                self.is_special_branch(current_branch_name):
            self.write_output(
                'Cannot close branch {}.'.format(current_branch_name), 'RED'
            )
            return False
        return True

    def run_command(self, description, *command):
        self.write_output(description, 'BG_GRAY')
        self.write_output(repr(command))
        self.write_output(subprocess.check_output(command), 'GRAY')

    def write_output(self, value, tag=''):
        self.txt_output['state'] = NORMAL
        if self.txt_output.get(1.0, END):
            self.txt_output.insert(END, '\n')
        self.txt_output.insert(END, value, tag)
        self.txt_output['state'] = DISABLED

    def run_commit(self, path, current_branch_name):
        if self.option_commit.get():
            new_branch_name = self.new_branch_name.get()
            if new_branch_name != current_branch_name:
                self.run_command(
                    'Changing branch name', 'hg', 'branch', '-R', path,
                    new_branch_name
                )
                current_branch_name = new_branch_name
            self.run_command(
                'Committing', 'hg', 'commit', '-R', path, '-v',
                '--message' + self.txt_commit_message.get(1.0, END).strip()
            )
        return current_branch_name

    def run_close(self, path, current_branch_name):
        if self.option_close.get():
            self.run_command(
                'Closing', 'hg', 'commit', '-R', path, '-v', '--close-branch',
                '--message=Close {} branch'.format(current_branch_name)
            )

    def get_current_revision(self, path, current_revision=''):
        if self.option_merge_test.get() or self.option_merge_production.get():
            command = 'hg', 'identify', '-i', '-R', path
            self.write_output(repr(command))
            current_revision = subprocess.check_output(command).strip()
        return current_revision

    def run_merge_test(self, path, current_revision):
        self.run_merge_generic(
            path, current_revision, self.option_merge_test,
            self.option_silent_merge_test, 'Test'
        )

    def run_merge_production(self, path, current_revision):
        self.run_merge_generic(
            path, current_revision, self.option_merge_production,
            self.option_silent_merge_production, 'Production'
        )

    def run_merge_generic(self, path, revision, merge, silent_merge, name):
        if merge.get():
            self.run_command('Pulling', 'hg', 'pull', '-R', path)
            self.run_command(
                'Updating to {}'.format(name), 'hg', 'update', '-R', path, name
            )
            use_merge_dialog = True
            if silent_merge.get():
                try:
                    self.run_command(
                        'Attempting silent merge', 'hg', 'merge', '-R', path,
                        '-t', 'internal:merge', '-r', revision
                    )
                except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
                    self.write_output(error.output, 'GRAY')
                    self.run_command(
                        'Silent merge failed; returning to {} branch'.format(
                            name), 'hg', 'update', '-C', '-R', path
                    )
                else:
                    use_merge_dialog = False
            if use_merge_dialog:
                self.run_command(
                    'Launching merge dialog', 'thg', 'merge', '-R', path, '-r',
                    revision
                )

    def run_push(self, path):
        if self.option_push.get():
            self.run_command(
                'Pushing', 'hg', 'push', '-R', path, '--new-branch'
            )

    @staticmethod
    def is_special_branch(branch_name):
        return branch_name in {'Test', 'Production', 'Site Redesign'}

    def set_close_branch_option_enabled(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def set_commit_files_enabled(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def set_merge_production_option_enabled(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def set_merge_test_option_enabled(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def set_silent_merge_production_option_enabled(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def set_silent_merge_test_option_enabled(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


def get_output(args):
    return subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TortoiseTool.main(sys.argv)
```